# git connection timeout after swapping server and remote

Tags: linux, git, dns, gitlab

i had to spin up a new gitlab server cuz the old one got destroyed. i created one on a new server and i pointed the domain to that new one. basically its a new server, but the url stayed the same.

after everything seems to work i swapped out the origin urls on my local machine and pushed all my projects via HTTPS to the new gitlab server and everything went fine.

but now when i access a server, where the project is installed and i want to pull it i get an error saying "Failed to connect to  port 443: connection timed out". i swapped out the url of the origin remote before ofc.

i dont think it has to do with the configuration of the new gitlab server because why would i be able to push it then? i can clone and pull on my local machine aswell, just not on the servers where the projects are installed

Comment: Port 443 is https. Connection timed out is ... exactly what it says it is. You dialed an Internet "phone number", the phone rang for 60 seconds or 5 minutes or however patient your computer is, nobody answered.

Comment: Your debug options are: trace the packets through the network to see if they're arriving. If not, that's the problem. If so, look at the logs on the server: is the web server running? Is it receiving the request? Is it acting on the request? Trace the replies through the network to see if they're arriving, and so on.